# Handle ajax requests with JSF (Primefaces)

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have this code :

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="locationChoice1" value="#{login.locationChoice1}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{login.chooseLocationType1}" update="locationChoice1 locationChoice2 positionChoice" />          
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

I would like to launch conditionnal update of `selectOneMenu` component if and only if the `selectBooleanCheckbox` is checked. I want to update it via ajax request.

To summarize, I want to link actions between ajax requests. When my ajax request above is finished, I want to launch another conditionnal ajax request based on `selectBooleanCheckbox` boolean value.

How can I do this please ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handle ajax events with Primefaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728836/handle-ajax-events-with-primefaces)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I´ve never seen an ajax beeing sent(or not) due to a conditional state of an element native in JSF

I would implement what you want adding an ajax inside my selectBoolean

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{login.chooseLocationType1()}" update="element"/>
```

then in the method chooseLocationType1 you could already handle the condition of the checkbox.

If you really want to send or not the post one thing you can do is to handle it using javascript. if you add **oncomplete=""** inside your p:ajax you can call a method in javascript and test if your checkbox is checked or not and then make a post using jquery or js

Comment: Thank you you for this answer. I'm new with JSF and probably I don't have the "JSF feeling" so perhaps I want to do something non "logical". My problem is better explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728836/handle-ajax-events-with-primefaces. I just want to link some lists between them.